MariaDB is killing connection after one minute for some reason
I am writing a program that sifts through the entire Wikipedia database and puts the data it encounters into a MariaDB Database. I use Kotlin for this, and at one minute run-time the server, which runs on localhost, kills the connection and the program terminates. I saw that this might be a WAIT_TIMEOUT issue, but I am actively communicating with the server the entire time, it's not idle or anything. I used this setup (Kotlin + MariaDB) for another project of mine, but it worked just fine there. I set up the MariaDB from a docker-compose.yml.
The error I'm getting is this: Exception in thread "main" org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to localhost:3306 : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
This is how the database gets set up:

import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import io.github.cdimascio.dotenv.dotenv
import me.koendev.database.*

val dotEnv = dotenv()
lateinit var articleService: ArticleService
lateinit var linkService: LinkService

fun main() {

    val database = Database.connect(
        url = dotEnv["DB_URL"],
        user = dotEnv["DB_USER"],
        password = dotEnv["DB_PASSWORD"],
        driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    )
    articleService = ArticleService(database)

This is where the program makes the calls to the database:
fun putInDatabase(title: String, link: String) {
    var articleID = articleService.read(title)
    if (articleID == null) {
        articleID = articleService.create(Article(title))
    }
}

And this is where the Articles Table gets set up:
package me.koendev.database

import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntity
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.IntEntityClass
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.EntityID
import org.jetbrains.exposed.dao.id.IntIdTable
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.select
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

data class Article(val title: String)

class ArticleItem(id: EntityID<Int>): IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : IntEntityClass<ArticleItem>(ArticleService.Articles)

    var title by ArticleService.Articles.title
}

class ArticleService(database: Database) {
    object Articles : IntIdTable() {
        val title = varchar("title", length = 256)
    }

    init {
        transaction(database) {
            SchemaUtils.createMissingTablesAndColumns(Articles)
        }
    }

    fun create(article: Article): Int {
        var id: Int? = null
        transaction {
            id = ArticleItem.new {
                title = article.title
            }.id.value
        }
        return id as Int
    }

    fun read(title: String): Int? {
        var id: Int? = null
        transaction {
            id = Articles.select {
                Articles.title eq title
            }.map {
                it[Articles.id]
            }.singleOrNull()?.value
        }
        return id
    }
}

I tried increasing the WAIT_TIMEOUT time, but that didn't work, and I would really like for the server to be connected indefinitely, as I am building a web-app from this.
Edit: I fixed it!
// Setting up DataBase
    val config = HikariConfig()
    config.jdbcUrl = dotEnv["DB_URL"]
    config.username = dotEnv["DB_USER"]
    config.password = dotEnv["DB_PASSWORD"]
    config.driverClassName = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
    config.maximumPoolSize = 10
    config.connectionTimeout = 30000
    config.idleTimeout = 600000
    val datasource = HikariDataSource(config)

I now use a connection pool from HikariCP, and it works great!

Normally with a database nowadays, you make the connection, perform the query, then immediately dispose of the connection. You don't use one connection for the life of the app, instead they automatically use a connection pool.

@AndrewMorton I see. But that still doesn't explain why the connection is killed after one minute exactly right? Or am I missing something?

Not really an answer, but since you're going through the entire Wikipedia database, I'd recommend writing/generating an SQL script for this, which can be ran locally on the MariaDB server. This will be much, much faster than doing it all over a database connection, even if that connection is local.

This error just indicate that socket has been closed without client to be aware of that.  Check server error log, or set logging "org.mariadb.jdbc" to trace, or check wireshark exchanges, to see if anything occurs just before the error

@Demipho Thanks, I'm gonna try doing that! This problem is now for future me ;)

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%timeout%';
